# Cordova 5 Gradle Build using HTTP Maven Repository

Tags: android, cordova, maven, gradle

I am trying to use the command `cordova build android` but am getting the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified
  > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > peer not authenticated
```

Where can I set gradle to use http instead of https? Is there any alternate way to avoid this?

I tried changing the build.gradle file in the project folder to use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0+'` but that didn't help.

Adding this also does not work

```
jcenter {
    url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample failing script?

Comment: This is mostly related with bad inet status, or no connection to maven site.

Comment: what kind of error log you got?